# Positive function with negative derivative must have negative second derivative at some point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the twice differentiable function $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$. Show that there is a point $x_{0} \in (0, \infty)$ such that $f''(x_{0}) \geq 0$

Concepts such as the mean value theorem and the limit definition of a derivative are available to me, but I am not sure how to proceed. I believe I should assume for contradiction that $f''(x)<0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$. I don't see how things like MVT can help me from here, though.

Comment: With $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ you mean that the codomain is the whole $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $x\in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: I apologize. It should be $(0, \infty)$

Comment: Okay, so, if $f'' <0$ everywhere, then for every $c > 1,$ $f'(c) < f'(1) < 0.$ For any $x>1,$ by the MVT, there exists $c \in (1,x)$ s.t. $f(x) - f(1) = (x-1) f'(c) < (x-1)f'(1)$. Show that for large enough $x,$ the above implies that $f(x) < 0,$ a contradiction. ($1$ is arbitrary here, you just need something bigger than $0$ in order to talk about the function evaluated at that point).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Why not write that as answer?